# Parse stream in x length chunks based on uint32 id

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qdatastream

I have little C/Qt experience and have a small parser that I need to port to Python. Is anyone able to explain how I can implement the below in Python? I understand what the result is, just can't understand how to achieve the uint32 instantiation and shift that results in different part lengths based on the 4 byte "id". I'm hoping to parse it using just native Python 3.5+ packages, numpy or similar is fine if it makes the typing convenient.

```
QDataStream stream(item);
stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
Items parts;
while (!stream.atEnd()) {
    quint32 partId;
    stream >> id;
    char *bytes;
    uint length;
    stream.readBytes(bytes, length);
    parts.append(QPair<quint32, QByteArray>(id, QByteArray(bytes, length)));
    delete bytes;
}
return parts;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in python the numeric types do not match those of C++ then QDataStream no longer uses the ">>" operator to obtain the value but has specific methods such as readUInt32.

Considering the following code that generates the data:

```cpp
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QFile file("file.dat");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
        qDebug() << file.error() << file.errorString();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    QDataStream stream(&file);
    stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_15);

    QVector <QPair<quint32, QByteArray>> data;
    data.append({1, "One"});
    data.append({2, "Two"});
    data.append({3, "Three"});

    for(const QPair<quint32, QByteArray> & d: qAsConst(data)){
        stream << d.first;
        stream.writeBytes(d.second.constData(), d.second.size());
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The following code gets the data:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QByteArray, QDataStream, QFile, QIODevice


file = QFile("file.dat")
if not file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly):
    print(file.error(), file.errorString())
    sys.exit(-1)

items = []

stream = QDataStream(file)
stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream.LittleEndian)
stream.setVersion(QDataStream.Qt_5_15)
while not stream.atEnd():
    id_ = stream.readUInt32()
    data = stream.readBytes()
    items.append((id_, QByteArray(data)))
print(items)
```

Output:

```
[(1, PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'One')), (2, PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'Two')), (3, PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'Three'))]
```

If PySide2 is used then the implementation changes a bit.

```py
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import QByteArray, QDataStream, QFile, QIODevice


file = QFile("file.dat")
if not file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly):
    print(file.error(), file.errorString())
    sys.exit(-1)

items = []

stream = QDataStream(file)
stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream.LittleEndian)
stream.setVersion(QDataStream.Qt_5_15)
while not stream.atEnd():
    id_ = stream.readUInt32()
    data = QByteArray()
    stream >> data
    items.append((id_, data))
print(items)
```

Output:

```
[(1, PySide2.QtCore.QByteArray(b'One')), (2, PySide2.QtCore.QByteArray(b'Two')), (3, PySide2.QtCore.QByteArray(b'Three'))]
```

### Update:

It is not possible to obtain the data if you do not use QDataStream since Qt uses its own format for each type of data, and this format is not a standard that can change with each version without notifying it. For this reason, the byteorder and the version of QDataStream used must be indicated.

### Update 2

Assuming that the format that QDataStream uses to pack quint32 and bytes is QDataStream.Qt_5_15 then a possible implementation is:

```py
import sys
import struct

items = []

with open("file.dat", "rb") as f:
    while True:
        try:
            (id_,) = struct.unpack("I", f.read(4))
            (length,) = struct.unpack("I", f.read(4))
            data = f.read(length)
        except (EOFError, struct.error) as e:
            break
        else:
            items.append((id_, data))

print(items)
```

Output:

```
[(1, b'One'), (2, b'Two'), (3, b'Three')]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your implementation is really clear and I understand it this context because PyQT5.Core implements the Qt types, I should have been more specific in that I'd like to use native python with as little dependencies as possible (though understand something like numpy might make typings more convenient. I've updated my original post to reflect.

Comment: @circa Short answer: you can't. Long answer: check out my updated answer

Comment: Hey thank you, that surprises me, the data is not actually generated by Qt, it's not known what process or language is used to create the binary, it just happens that this parser was originally implemented as a prototype in Qt, and also C# and I need to move it to Python. I get uint32 is just a 4byte unsigned integer, I can read it with `struct.unpack("I", stream.read(4))` but that gives me 4 byte blocks and not the "magic" length of the original integer...

Comment: @circa If you want more help you must provide  a [MRE], that is, I mean a clear and precise description of the format (for example, how many bytes for each data, in the case of uint32 it is simple but how are the bytes encoded? Is the data indicated before or after the data?) OR at least input data (rawdata) and what you should get OR the code in any language that generates the data. I point this out because I am assuming that the data was generated using QDataStream.

Comment: @circa It would also be interesting to show the code that reads the data in C# that probably does not use an external library but implements with its own tools.

Comment: I actually worked it out thanks to this :) all that's happening is that it's reading a uint32 value, then shifting the stream 4 bytes to the right, which is another 4 byte unsigned int representing the value of the section length. After that section you hit another ID indicator and another length and so on so cased closed :) cheers!